# method kaptKotlin not found in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, kapt

I try to run a task that copies a file after kaptKotlin finishes.
I use Spring in combination with Kotlin and want to copy the generated spring-configuration-metadata.json file to the META-INF folder. If this could be achieved without the use of a own copy task it would help me a lot, too.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.61"
}

kaptKotlin {
    finalizedBy copyPropertiesMetadata
}

task copyPropertiesMetadata(type: Copy) {
    from file("$buildDir/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json")
    into file("src/main/resources/META-INF")
}
```

When I try to do this as in the example, I get the following error message:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'kapt-test'.
>   Could not find method kaptKotlin() for arguments [build_7sekpnn17qad87i9lpu664i61$_run_closure1@66bc8629] on root project 'kapt-test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a way to do it, thanks to [this site](https://blog.softwaremill.com/my-task-whats-wrong-with-your-gradle-task-82312100c595?gi=d6bbf3bb01c6#96ec). I have to do it the other way around:

```
task copyPropertiesMetadata(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'kaptKotlin') {
    from file("$buildDir/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json")
    into file("src/main/resources/META-INF")
}
```

When "kaptKotlin" is given as string it works properly